# Sinatra build REST API documentation

Tags: ruby, api, rest, documentation, sinatra

I have been looking all night for a gem to generate an API documentation from my sinatra routes. I should be able to specify with inline comments.

I have found https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-api-docs & https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-croon

but both just don't seem to work with my setup and are outdated too..

The other option was yard with some sinatra plugin, but that does not generate REST API specific layout when generating the docs.

Does anyone have any tools they know about?

All the information i want to reference for each route:

Object: Groups

Route: POST /create

Params:  Name of the group

Output:

```
{
  "name": "group",
  "members": []
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Apiary.io](http://apiary.io/blueprint), it looks pretty well designed and uses a Markdown-style domain-specific language to describe your API. Plus its free while still in beta.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Sinatra Yard](https://github.com/rkh/yard-sinatra)? I've used it, with some modifications to Yard, to produce my API docs.